# Stripe Alamofire response looks like array with elements separated by a semicolon

Tags: php, json, swift, alamofire

I am making an Alamofire request but getting an odd response. (Swift 3)

```
Alamofire.request(url, parameters: params).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON { response in

        if let result = response.result.value  {
            let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")

        }
```

This prints the following:

```
JSON: {
    message = "Payment has been charged";
    status = Success;
}
```

Looks solid, but I'm having trouble with two pieces of this response. First off, what is the type of this response. Array? Any? Dictionary? Second, how would I access an element in it. For instance, I want to check to see if the status equals Success.

The last piece of information I have is that my backend (in PHP) produces this with:

```
$response = array("status"=>"Success","message"=>"Payment has been charged");
```

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: did you tried doing `print(JSON.status);` OR  `print(JSON.message);`

Comment: It's an array.  Have you worked with PHP arrays before?  See the friendly manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php You can access elements using `$response['status']` and `$response['message']`

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have tried those. They give me the error: value of type 'NSDictionary' has no member 'status'.

Comment: @PhilipCouling So I am pretty new to PHP, but I have worked arrays. I agree, `$response["status"]` helps on my backend but that won't do anything for my in my Swift file I don't think. One other piece of info I'll add is that I am sending the response by calling `echo json_encode($response);` Would this have anything to do with my problem?